# SQL returns less results when using UNION?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that doesn't give me all the results when I add in the union and the second half. The first half will give me all 6 results, using the union, I only get 5.

There are 3 patients with their own [chart number], each have 2 items that should be displayed. if the [CPTCode] is the same for both entries of a patient, only one of the two entries show up when i add the union (it gives me all 6 with the same [cptcode] without the union). The second half isn't actually pulling any information with what i'm doing right now, but it is needed.

```
select      /*Patients with chart numbers*/
   B1.[chart Number],
   '0' as newPatient, 
   isnull(Lytec.[Last Name],'') as [Last Name], 
   isnull(Lytec.[First Name],'') as [First Name],
   isnull(Address.[Name],
   Lytec.[Facility Code]) as [Facility], 
   isnull(B1.DOS,'') as [DOS], 
   isnull(Ins.[Name],
   Lytec.[Primary Code]) as [Primary Code],
   isnull(B1.[CPTCode],'') as cptCode, 
   isnull(B1.[Units],'') as [Units], 
   isnull(B1.[Modifiers],'') as [Modifiers], 
   isnull(B1.[cptCodeOther],'') as [cptCodeOther],
   isnull(B1.[cptCode2],'') as cptCode2, 
   isnull(B1.[Units],'') as [Units2], 
   isnull(B1.[Modifiers2],'') as [Modifiers2], 
   isnull(B1.[cptCodeOther2],'') as [cptCodeOther2],
   'name' as ProviderName
from 
   [sandboxmr].dbo.patient Lytec
   left join [dbo].[Billing] B1 on B1.[Chart Number] = Lytec.[Chart Number]
   left join [sandboxmr].dbo.[Address] Address on Lytec.[Facility Code] = Address.[Code]
   left join [sandboxmr].dbo.[Insurance] Ins on Lytec.[Primary Code] = Ins.[Code]
where 
   b1.[userid] = 54
   and (b1.[DateSubmitted] >= convert(varchar(25),'2011-8-31',101) 
   and b1.[DateSubmitted] <= convert(varchar(25),'2011-9-22',101))

union

select      /*Patients without chart numbers*/
   cast(P.id as varchar(15)) as [chart number], 
   '1' as newPatient,  
   isnull(P.[Last Name],'') as [Last Name], 
   isnull(P.[First Name],'') as [First Name],
   isnull(Address.[Name],
   P.[Facility Code]) as [Facility], 
   isnull(IV.DOS,isnull(SV.DOS,'')) as [DOS], 
   isnull(Ins.[Name],P.[Primary_Code]) as [Primary Code],
   isnull(IV.[cptCode],isnull(SV.[cptCode],'')) as cptCode, 
   isnull(IV.[Units],isnull(SV.[Units],'')) as [Units], 
   isnull(IV.[Modifiers],isnull(SV.[Modifiers],'')) as [Modifiers],    
   isnull(IV.[cptcodeother],isnull(SV.[cptcodeother],'')) as [cptCodeOther],
   isnull(IV.[cptCode2],isnull(SV.[cptCode2],'')) as cptCode2, 
   isnull(IV.Units2,isnull(SV.Units2,'')) as [Units2], 
   isnull(IV.[Modifiers2],isnull(SV.[Modifiers2],'')) as [Modifiers2], 
   isnull(IV.[cptCodeOther2],isnull(SV.[cptCodeOther2],'')) as [cptCodeOther2],
   'Name' as ProviderName
from 
   [DNSList].[dbo].[Patient] P 
   left join [dbo].[InitialVisits] IV on p.emr_id = IV.patientid
   left join [dbo].[SubsequentVisits] SV on p.emr_id = SV.patientid
   left join [sandboxmr].dbo.[Address] Address on P.[Facility Code] = Address.[Code]
left join [sandboxmr].dbo.[Insurance] Ins on P.[Primary_Code] = Ins.[Code]
where 
   p.[userid] = 54 
   and p.[Chart Number] is null
   and (p.[DateSubmitted] >= convert(varchar(25),'2011-8-31',101) 
   and p.[DateSubmitted] <= convert(varchar(25),'2011-9-22',101))
order by 
   [Last Name]
```

Why does it do this, and how can I fix it? I've tried adding a `distinct` to the [cptcode] area, but it of course generates an error.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Do you intend to use a `UNION` (no duplicates) or a `UNION ALL` (allow duplicates between the two queries)?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`UNION` will eliminate duplicate rows, whether they come between the two result sets or, as in your case, within just one result set. Try using `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. yes it worked. and yes, the second set shouldn't return any of those results, that why i was confused as to why it was interferring, didn't realize the union suppressed results.

Comment: damn, I knew that union removes duplicates, but thought it was between result sets.  Never knew it can be within 1 result set.  This changes things.  ....***sneaks away to go fix some queries on production....***

Answer (score 35):

I believe you need to use `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` suppresses duplicates by default

Answer (score 3):

A little background here. Technically a table is a **set** of rows. This is in the mathematical sense of sets.

Two important properties of mathematical sets are:

- A set is unordered
- A set has no duplicates

The first point is why row order is not reliable unless you add an `ORDER BY` clause. The second is one reason you should always have a primary key to ensure that each rows is indeed distinct.

The `UNION` operation is a set operation and (a) combines two sets, (b) produces a set. In order to maintain the integrity of a set the `UNION` will remove duplicate rows.

Unfortunately, there is no real way of guaranteeing whether two rows are supposed to be same, so SQL will simply compare the values in the `SELECT` clauses. If those values are the same, then SQL decides there is a duplicate.

This can lead to an exaggerated example:

```sql
SELECT state FROM customers
UNION
SELECT state FROM customers;
```

In principle, the `state` value is produced twice, duplicate values are removed, and what you have is a long-winded way of saying `SELECT DISTINCT`.

The set behaviour is also why you can’t have an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statements: once you order a data set, it is no longer a true set.

(Yes, you can have an `ORDER BY` clause, but it isn’t attached to a `SELECT` statement, but rather to the resulting `UNION`).

Of course, SQL isn’t just about pure mathematics, so it includes two features which break the set:

- You can order a set with an `ORDER BY` clause.

  However, you can only do this after the rest of the work is complete, which is why it’s the last clause.
- You can include duplicates using the `UNION ALL` clause.